# Replace function not working in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, replace, formula

when i provide string stknummer = "*VU-NR:-93.10xxxxxxxx_2-12-2011*" to this function:

```
whileprintingrecords;

shared stringvar tstnummer;
shared stringvar stknummer;

local stringvar tst;
local stringvar stk;
local stringvar bc;

tst := tstnummer;
stk := stknummer;

//why is this not evaluated?
tst := Replace (tstnummer,":" ,"_" );
tst := Replace (tstnummer,"." ,"_" );
tst := Replace (tstnummer,"=" ,"_" );
tst := Replace (tstnummer,"/" ,"_" );
tst := Replace (tstnummer,"\" ,"_" );
tst := Replace (tstnummer,"?" ,"_" );
tst := Replace (tstnummer,"#" ,"_" );
tst := Replace (tstnummer,"." ,"_" );
tst := Replace (tstnummer,"*" ,"_" );
tst := Replace (tstnummer,"|" ,"_" );
tst := Replace (tstnummer,"<" ,"_" );
tst := Replace (tstnummer,">" ,"_" );
tst := Replace (tstnummer," " ,"-" );

//and this neither?
stk := Replace (stknummer,":" ,"_" );
stk := Replace (stknummer,"." ,"_" );
stk := Replace (stknummer,"=" ,"_" );
stk := Replace (stknummer,"/" ,"_" );
stk := Replace (stknummer,"\" ,"_" );
stk := Replace (stknummer,"?" ,"_" );
stk := Replace (stknummer,"#" ,"_" );
stk := Replace (stknummer,"." ,"_" );
stk := Replace (stknummer,"*" ,"_" );
stk := Replace (stknummer,"|" ,"_" );
stk := Replace (stknummer,"<" ,"_" );
stk := Replace (stknummer,">" ,"_" );
stk := Replace (stknummer," " ,"-" );


//select file output format
if {?barcode_type} = true
then (if trim(stk) ="" 
     then  
        bc:= "*" + tst + "_" + totext(dateValue({@signdate})) + "*"
     else
        (
        bc:= "*" + stk + "_" + totext(dateValue({@signdate})) + "*");;)
else bc := "*" + tst + "_" + totext(dateValue({@signdate})) + "*"
```

The result is that no replacements are made (i.e. the : is still there)

when i put    Replace(stk, ":", "_")    in the bottom function like:

```
//select file output format
if {?barcode_type} = true
then (if trim(stk) ="" 
     then  
        bc:= "*" + tst + "_" + totext(dateValue({@signdate})) + "*"
     else
        (
        bc:= "*" + Replace (stk, ":", "_") + "_" + totext(dateValue({@signdate})) + "*");;)
else bc := "*" + tst + "_" + totext(dateValue({@signdate})) + "*"
```

The replacement is done correctly.

Why are the replacements not done in the first example?

I good put all replacements in the function but that not all too elegant....

THanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, you're going to be mad about this one :)

The Replace() function is being evaluated... but each time you're overwriting the variables stk and tst with only a single replacement of *the original strings,* tstnummer and stknummer. When all the Replaces() are done, you're simply left with a string with no white space character. Need to change to this...

```
...
tst := Replace (tst,":" ,"_" );
tst := Replace (tst,"." ,"_" );
tst := Replace (tst,"=" ,"_" );
...
stk := Replace (stk,":" ,"_" );
stk := Replace (stk,"." ,"_" );
```

Comment: So the replace blocks are applied on the original strings? but then the : character should be removed? How would i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

+1 -- That's caught ME before.

In your first assignment,

```
tst := tstnummer;
```

You're giving 'tst' a value.

In your first active statement,

```
tst := Replace (tstnummer,":" ,"_" );
```

You are RE-assigning a value to 'tst'.  EVERY active statement re-assigns 'tst' with the results of REPLACE() -- which acts on the value in 'tstnummer'.
'Tstnummer' NEVER CHANGES.  'Tst' is repeatedly assigned the results of the LAST REPLACE()

Instead, after you have assigned 'tst' a value, you want to re-assign it with the results of REPLACE() -- on the variable 'Tst'.  Each time an active statement is processed, the value of 'tst' is updated, and the NEXT active statement processes the "new" 'tst'.

It sounds confusing, but if you step through it, you will see.
'Tstnummer' stays the same

Next we'll play with REGEX!  (just kidding).